# Tag on a question preceded by a minus interpreted incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, questions

If I want to tag some question **[php-server]** and mistype that as "**php -server**" (white space inserted), it comes out as the following display:

> **[php]** not **[server]**

See [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1762630/list), [as well as another](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2197418/revisions), and an example [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/30118/list).

Comment: I don't think that's a bug, that's user error.

Comment: I've also seen this on a migrated question whose tags were auto-cleaned, but unfortunately I can't remember what the resulting tag was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to enter tags as [php] [-server] now. At least when I try it on dev, it gets stripped out.

Comment: I just saw an example over at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391767 The original tags on that post were just `c#` and `post` and then the other two were added later. That might be a clue.

Answer (score 3):

Tags are not allowed to be preceded by "-"

Works as designed.

Comment: I guess the engine could automatically eliminate a white space in such case.

Comment: That would cause the reverse issue - if someone attempted to tag a question "C" and "--x" then they'd end up with "c--x" I'm curious what the issue is - I obviously don't see a problem with the current implementation, but you are trying to solve something.  Is the problem, "The system should correct user mistakes" or "The system should accept '-' at the start of a tag" ?

Comment: IMO the problem is that the system should correct mistakes (or I guess it is better to call this data normalization since really having tags starting with a minus doesn't seem useful).

Comment: This is not an error! What if somebody legitimately wanted to search for PHP, but nothing to do with servers?