# Bug in rendered "not" tag?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, rendering

Using Firefox 3.5.7 on Windows XP, I loaded SO's front page to see this:

[alt text http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/1979/so1.png](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/1979/so1.png)

The offending HTML snippet is:

```
<div class="tags t--0">
     not&nbsp;<a href="/questions/tagged/0" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged '0'" rel="tag">0</a> 
</div>
```

[alt text http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/9201/so2.png](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/9201/so2.png)

The [particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2178565/revisions) has since been closed.

I can confirm this rendering bug happens with IE 8 as well.

Comment: Which is also a dupe of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30319/tag-on-a-question-preceded-by-a-minus-interpreted-incorrectly